# Output of console.log is different in Chrome and Firefox?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, console.log

For a simple statement such as:

```
console.log(someObj);
```

### Firefox (Acutal Output)

[image: Firefox]

### Chrome (Expected Output)

[image: Chrome]

Why are some properties such as `latitutde`, `longitude`, `type` etc. hidden from Firefox console? Is there a setting that I accidently enabled/disabled on Firefox?

I also see them grouped under the `metadatas` property in Firefox. Why is that so?

Comment: It's really hard to say without us knowing what `someObj` is and what you are expecting to see.  Maye try saving it as a JSON string and then comparing to see what the "real" differences are: `console.log(JSON.stringify(someObj, null, 2));`

Comment: Also note that the `__accessor__` object you've expanded is not representative of your actual code, it's an internal thing for how objects work: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/proto

Comment: @ChrisBarr The output that Chrome is showing is the one that is the expected one. Not sure why Firefox seems to be hiding that information.

Comment: Can you put the object and demo of this to put on jsfiddle or codepen?